# How do I use a target = blank for <a> tags in iframe?

Tags: html, href, target

My page is an iframe in the main page. And hung a link like `<a href="http://www.google.co.kr" target="_blank"> google </a>` in an iframe. However, the links do not operate. `target = '_ self'` is a well operation, `target = '_ blank'` is not operated. It works fine on the main page.

Why would it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure the issue have something to do with the sandbox attribute. It seems that you can add the attribute "allow-top-navigation", change the link to 'target=_parent' and should works.

Here is a little bit of documentation [from the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe):

#### About the sandbox attr:

- `allow-top-navigation`: Allows the embedded browsing context to navigate (load) content to the top-level browsing context. If this keyword is not used, this operation is not allowed.

Comment: I solved the problem by adding the **allow-popups** from the sandbox attribute.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Check the iframe sandbox attribute - "allow-top-navigation" - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp

Comment: @TomSarduy - There's nothing wrong with w3schools. There might have been quite a few misleading information on that site before, but they have changed a lot these years. Take a look a [W3Fools](http://www.w3fools.com/), they have confirmed that all of their issues have been fixed, and you can no longer find any example on their tracking site.

Comment: @TomSarduy - when the information they provide is correct I don't see a reason why not to use.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: I know, but is not comparable with MDN for example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: @TomSarduy - Well MDN is definitely better in covering all the technical details. I use it all the time. But all I was saying is we should stop rejecting w3schools as a legit tutorial site for new learners. :)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: I personally have bad experience with that site, and we can't be so sure that the info is correct. I know they have been working on it, but for me is just a website with good SEO ;)

Comment: @TomSarduy - You might also want to check out the official [W3C wiki](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/html/elements/iframe) for absolutely correct info.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: But that's a wiki, when I want to be serious I would go with http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/iframe.html#iframe, jeje ;)

Comment: @TomSarduy Most of the time the specification is not really that useful since it does not address browser compatibility issues. Wikis are better because they do talk about them, and might even provide some polyfills.